# Matrix Algebra Question

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Could someone explain how to do matrix algebra?

$$4\begin{bmatrix} 1-2a \\a
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} b \\12
\end{bmatrix}$$

I apologize for the layout, I don't know how to fix it. When I've put a comma, this signifies that it should be on the bottom.

Much appreciated.

Comment: I have fixed it. You can see my codes in the question's edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is solving two equations:

$$4(1-a)=b$$
$$4a=12$$

I suggest to start with the second one.

Comment: @Charlie See this for Basic Tutorial of $LaTeX$ https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: OK, cheers. Question makeds sense now.